# get the attribute data-* from tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Am trying to get the data-target attribute from img tags

Html:

```
<img src="my src" alt="my_alt" data-target= "my_target1" />
<img src="my src" alt="my_alt" data-target= "my_target2" />
<img src="my src" alt="my_alt" data-target= "my_target3" />
<img src="my src" alt="my_alt" data-target= "my_target4" />
```

Ruby:

```
my_html.css("img").each do |img|
 puts img[:src]
 puts img[:data-target]
end
```

img[:src] works fine but not the case for img[:data-target]

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754437/extracting-html5-data-attributes-from-a-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only a matter of referencing symbols that have dashes (or other special characters) in them.

```
puts img[:'data-target']
```

Answer (score 0):

for this type of data you will have to make the tags using the rails way

```
<%= content_tag(:img, :src => "#2012-09-29", :alt => "my_alt" :data => { :my_data => "my_target1" } ) %>
```

then you can access it using `:my_data`